# What does it mean graphically if a function is twice differentiable

Tags: calculus, functions, numerical-methods

What I mean to say is that we say that if a function is only differentiable once then it has a non-zero slope. Similarly on the same lines by graphical interpretation what is meant if we call a function to be twice differentiable?

Comment: "if a function is differentiable once then it has a non-zero slope" actually this is not correct. f(x)=c is differentiable

Comment: Being twice differentiable might be thought as telling you how the slope changes in a smoothness sense

Comment: @Rahul f'(x) =0 then if c is a constant does this not mean a 0 slope

Comment: @Henry Yes I think I get you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @PowerSurge: “The slope is zero” and “the slope is undefined” are two completely different things, which you seem to be confusing.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes you are right ... I was confused...  I get the point and yes it does answer the question.... Just one thing more in Newtons Method one of the methods for calculation of roots, we have a condition that the function is supposed to be twice differentiable. Would you know why that is Basically I am trying to link the two. Thanks

Comment: @Moo what I got was that being twice differentiable was required to reach the necessary convergence.

Comment: @Moo Thanks Understood.

Comment: The Newton's method issue is (interesting and) distinct from the question as stated, and I think it's not ideal to leave it in the comments if you want it answered. I'm not sure, however, if it's preferable to edit this question (new title, new body), or to delete this and ask the question you're actually interested in. Since there are no posted answers, it may not matter, though you might ask a moderator for advice.

Comment: I think I'll ask a new question.... Cause I'm new to this and don't really know much about how this works.